# Winapi: Identifying display for disabled monitor

Tags: winapi, multiple-monitors

### Goal

I have 2 screens and a TV connected to my PC. I want to easily toggle between:

1. TV as primary and only activated monitor
2. The two screens in a specific arrangement with the TV deactivated

I know there are tools out there, but they don't quite do what I want and aren't open source.

### What works

I have no problems rearranging monitors and changing the primary monitor. I followed [this post](https://blog.lohr.dev/primary-display-windows), which detailed everything I needed.

### Problem

Windows differentiates between display (?) and monitor (actual screen/tv), where each display manages multiple monitors. Each of the monitors is listed multiple times under different displays. The configuration function ([ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexa)) takes the name of a **display**, not of a monitor. This means I need to know which display manages which exact monitor.

### Example

Partial log output when my main screen (VG248) was activated and TV + second screen (ASUS VS228) were deactivated:

```
Display:
    DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1
    DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
    State: active
    Monitor:
        DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
        State: active
        Friendly Name: VG248
    Monitor:
        DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor1
        State: inactive
        Friendly Name: ASUS VS228
    Monitor:
        DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor2
        State: inactive
        Friendly Name: SONY TV  *30
Display:
    DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY2
    DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
    State: inactive
    Monitor:
        DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0
        State: inactive
        Friendly Name: ASUS VS228
    Monitor:
        DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor1
        State: inactive
        Friendly Name: SONY TV  *30
...
```

(left out for brevity: DISPLAY3 and DISPLAY4 contain the same monitors as DISPLAY2)

It's easy to see that DISPLAY1 manages the main screen, because it's state is active and it doesn't show up anywhere else. But which display do I configure to turn on the TV? Displays 2, 3, and 4 all contain both the second screen and the TV. There is no way for me to tell which monitor will turn on if I enable display 2. I hoped it was always the monitor at index 0, but that doesn't seem to be true.

I believe that active monitors show up only once under their active display and inactive monitors always show up under every display. But it's hard to pin down since everything changes depending on the current combination of activated/deactivated displays.

### Question

I can find some heuristics that might let me guess correctly 90% of the time, but that's very unsatisfying. Is there a way to find out (or even configure) which deactivated display represents which deactivated monitor?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're looking for exactly. The API for that should be the "Connecting and Configuring Display" (CCD) API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-apis . Here is a (C#) sample code that uses interop and dumps all topology paths https://pastebin.com/raw/ncZx1EN2. You can play with it and filter differently see if it gives what you're looking for.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks to the link you posted I found that there is a completely different API I can use to change the display arrangement: [SetDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig). I will see if that helps, it seems to offer much more fine-grained control. I was already using QueryDisplayConfig to figure out the friendly names of the monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to solve the issue with ChangeDisplaySettingsEx. But SetDisplayConfig offers everything I need - except I didn't test changing the refresh rate yet.

If someone with similar issues finds this question in the future: use SetDisplayConfig.